# CMAKE Error /usr/bin/cc -- broken

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to compile a simple **.cpp** file but when i issue **cmake ..** its throw error

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.7.3

-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.7.3
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc

-- **Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- broken**

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "/usr/bin/cc" is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: /home/user/jagdish/hello/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec3772316685/fast"

  /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3772316685.dir/build.make
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3772316685.dir/build

  make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/jagdish/hello/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report
  /home/user/jagdish/hello/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1

  Building C object
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3772316685.dir/testCCompiler.c.o

  /usr/bin/cc -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3772316685.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
  -c /home/user/jagdish/hello/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c

  Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec3772316685

  /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3772316685.dir/link.txt --verbose=1

  /usr/bin/cc CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3772316685.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o
  cmTryCompileExec3772316685 -rdynamic

  collect2: error: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault]

  make[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec3772316685] Error 1

  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/jagdish/hello/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  make: *** [cmTryCompileExec3772316685/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/jagdish/hello/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/user/jagdish/hello/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: Something in your setup is quite badly broken when `ld` is segfaulting. What happens if you try to reproduce this by hand: write a trivial C program "Hello, World!" or similar and compile it with `gcc -o hello hello.c`?

Comment: Throws error collect2: error: ld terminated with signal 11

Comment: Sorry found the ans i had broken g++ and gcc so i fixed now

Comment: please write up an answer and mark it as accepted. explain what you mean by "broken" in the answer, and what you did to resolve the issue- did you install a new compiler?